# If-then-else simplified in Ocaml

Tags: if-statement, operators, conditional-statements, ocaml

I'm starting in Ocaml and one of the questions that i have is: How to simplify this segment of code

*if f (x) < h then f (x) else h*

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this

```
min (f x) h
```

(I hope this isn't a school assignment. Better to figure those out yourself.)